# Include the contents of a dependency in (mappings in packageBin)

Tags: sbt

We assemble multiple projects into one jar:

```
val asmDep = "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-asm" % "5.0.3-scala-3"

lazy val compiler = (project in file(".") / "src" / "compiler")
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(asmDep),
    mappings in Compile in packageBin :=
      (mappings in Compile in packageBin).value ++
      (mappings in Compile in packageBin in LocalProject("interactive")).value ++
      [...])
```

I'd like to also include the content of the `asmDep` dependency (it's a single JAR) into the project package. Is there an easy way to get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly).

I'm not sure if `asmDep` is the only dependency out of many in your project you want to add to your package or not, but there's a few different configuration options available in `sbt-assembly` that might suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing it manually, `sbt-assembly` didn't fit exactly our needs, but it was a great reference for writing our own method.